# How to properly append array of element to array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have these array and array of objects in my React code:

```
var A = [
  {id: 1, name: "han"},
  {id: 2, name: "mohd"},
]

var B = [100, 200];
```

and I want to append B to A, so that the output becomes something like this:

```
var A = [
  {id: 1, name: "han", score: "100"},
  {id: 2, name: "mohd", score: "200},
]
```

I tried doing it with the code below:

```
var newArray = [];

for (let k = 0; k < A.length; k++) {
        newArray = B.map(score => ({...A[k], score}));
}

return newArray;
```

However, the code above returns this output when console logged:

```
newArray = [
  {id: 2, name: "mohd", score: "100"},
  {id: 2, name: "mohd", score: "200},
]
```

It only appends the elements to the latest object, instead of to all objects. Anyone knows what is wrong with my code? Thank you!

Comment: If the lengths for A and B are the same and its just merging it. You can use `k` as index for A and B and do something like `A[k].score = B[k]`. I would urge you to learn the basics of programming either via youtube or a book

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to use `map` you don't also need a loop since `map` will iterate over the array of objects, and return new array with new objects containing the `score` property.

Use the second parameter of the callback - [the index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#parameters) - to identify which element of `b` we should be adding as the score.

```js
const a = [
  {id: 1, name: 'han'},
  {id: 2, name: 'mohd'},
];

const b = [100, 200];

// `map` over `a` making sure we get the object
// in each iteration as well as its index
const out = a.map((obj, i) => {

  // Create a new object adding in the
  // new `score` property using the element in `b`
  // that matches the index
  return { ...obj, score: b[i] };

});

console.log(out);
```

Comment: Nice explanation, i understood it right away. Thank you for the kind answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
const C = A.map((value, idx) =>({
   ...value,
   score: B[idx],
 }));

console.log(C)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your both array lenght Will same then use this method

```
 var A = [
      {id: 1, name: "han"},
      {id: 2, name: "mohd"},
    ]
    
    var B = [100, 200];
    console.log(A.map((x,i)=>
        {return {
            ...x,
        score:B[i]
        }
        }
                     ))
```

If not sure About use this eg..

```
var A = [
  {id: 1, name: "han"},
  {id: 2, name: "mohd"},
   {id: 2, name: "mohd"},
]

var B = [100, 200];
console.log(A.map((x,i)=>
    {return {
        ...x,
    score:!B[i]?0:B[i]
    }
    }
                 ))
```

Answer (score 0):

The input Data Structure is not really good...
What if array don't have the same size ?

## With your data model:

```
var A = [
  {id: 1, name: "han"},
  {id: 2, name: "mohd"},
]

var B = [100, 200];
    
Object.entries(A).map((entry,i) => { 
  return {
    ...entry[1], //Object from A 
    score: B[i] // Get I index from B
   }
  })
```

## Ideal DataModel

```
var B = [
 {id: 1, score:100 },
 {id: 2, score:200 }
]
```

and merge A an B with id.

Answer (score 0):

You try with that method.

```
let  A = [
    {id: 1, name: "han"},
    {id: 2, name: "mohd"},
  ]
  
  let  B = [100, 200];

  let newArray = [];
  let newObj ={};

  for(let i=0;i<A.length;i++){
    for(let j=0;j<B.length;j++){
        newObj = Object.assign(A[i],{score: B[j]})
    }
     newArray.push(newObj);
  }
console.log(newArray);
```